# Postgres left join is truncating rows

Tags: postgresql

I would just like a join to return 0 rather than dropping rows. Currently, if I try to join the two tables and count the number of items for each subscription, it will work fine:

```
SELECT S.id, count(I.id) FROM "Subscription" S
LEFT JOIN "Item" I on I.id = S.item_id
WHERE S.status = 1
GROUP BY S.id
```

returns:

```
id | count(I.id) 
1       4
2       3
3       2
```

whereas:

```
SELECT S.id, count(I.id) FROM "Subscription" S
LEFT JOIN "Item" I on I.id = S.item_id
WHERE S.status = 1
AND I.status IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY S.id
```

returns:

```
id | count(I.id) 
1       3
```

I realise this is probably how Postgres should work, but Im used to using MySQL.

I've tried **aggregate functions** to produce the desired effect as well as **conditional statements** and **right, full and outer joins** but cannot seem to get it working the way I want.

What if I want to return all of the users with status 1 but show 0 items if they have no items with status 1,2 or 3?

From [this documentation](http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/11/sql-outer-joins.html) it seems like the code Im using should work.

The desired result is:

```
id | count(I.id) 
1       3
2       0
3       0
```

Comment: Please try to explain better the expected result that you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT S.id, count(I.id) FROM "Subscription" S
LEFT JOIN "Item" I on I.id = S.item_id AND I.status IN (1,2,3)
WHERE S.status = 1
GROUP BY S.id
```

Your old `where` clause was filtering the results **after** the `LEFT JOIN` turning it into a `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Perfect! You absolute beauty thats been having me round the houses for ages. I wasnt aware you could use "on" and "and" in a join statement. Can you do this in MySQL?

Comment: @JackalopeZero Haven't tried it in MySQL but I am 99% sure you can do it in any RDBMS.

Comment: @JackalopeZero Of course - a left join predicate is an expression like anything else.